# Visualization/analytics tools for MongoDB on Windows

Tags: mongodb, business-intelligence

I have MongoDB on Windows and it seems the MongDB BI Connector is not available for Windows.

Will it be made available so I can use e.g. Tableau to analyze my data?

Comment: If you have unique requirements like this, I'd suggest go ahead and file a feature request at https://jira.mongodb.org

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB team has made [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) to visualise data

If you wish to use their payed tool then it's a solution.

(it's free for evaluation and development )

Answer (score 0):

Compass is a great tool, but it's more about data exploration and maintenance than visualisation. While it does show some basic graphs, these are limited to showing the spread of data across a schema.

For a more complete MongoDB data visualisation solution, check out [MongoDB Charts](https://mongodb.com/charts). Charts is a first-party MongoDB tool designed to visualise data from your MongoDB collections. You can create charts with a drag and drop interface, arrange the charts onto your dashboards, and embed them into your own applications without code.

Charts is available as a part of MongoDB Atlas, or it can be installed as an on-prem server.

[image: MongoDB Charts screenshot]